# simple OR search with attributes in thinking-sphinx?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

Is it possible to perform a simple "OR" search in thinking-sphinx? here is a small example in pseudocode.

```
define_index do
  ...
  has :attr_a, :attr_b
end

Object.search @q, :conditions => {...some cond...}, :with => {:attr_a => value_a OR :attr_b => value_b}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, though it's a little more complicated than most queries - you'll need to use Sphinx's select query to work through it. The [docs cover this situation](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/common_issues.html#or_attributes).

Comment: yes i read that part, but it didn't work. i tried something like this:

`with_display = "*, (attr_a = value_a AND attr_b = value_b) OR (attr_c = value_c AND attr_d = value_d) AS display"
Object.search q,
 :conditions   => {...}, 
  :sphinx_select => with_display,
  :with          => {'display' => 1}`

Comment: I found this error `ThinkingSphinx::SphinxError: index medium_core: no such filter attribute 'display'`. What is the 'display' attribute in this case? Is it a column in table?